# Dagger 2, not getting component instance

Tags: android, dagger-2

Trying to understand Dagger2 implementation with this [link1](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-on-android--cms-23345) and this [link2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Dagger/article.html)

In the the cases in the last we have to take the instance of Compenent class with this : When you try to create a new object of the interface with the @Component annotation, you have to do it using the prefix Dagger_

I am trying to do that in my class but the file shows not able to find the class.

```
VehicleComponent component = Dagger_VehicleComponent.builder().vehicleModule(new VehicleModule()).build();
```

not able to get the class Dagger_VehicleComponent.

This is my gradle file :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vogella.android.tutsplusdagger"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11' // if you use the support libraries
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'

    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

}
```

Anyone can help why this problem is being faced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dagger build the intermediate classes at the time of building the project. So you have to build the project before adding the components or modules. Otherwise your build components will not be found. Also it will be `DaggerVehicleComponent` instant of `Dagger_VehicleComponent`